# Unable to Override Tailwind CSS Default Minimum Font Size of 12px

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to set a font size smaller than 12px using Tailwind CSS. However, it seems that Tailwind CSS enforces a default minimum font size of 12px, preventing me from achieving the desired font size. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<p className="text-xxs font-[400] md:text-base 3xl:text-[clamp(16px,1vw,32px)]">
{title}
</p>
```

And here's my Tailwind CSS configuration where I've attempted to set a font size smaller than 12px:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        xxs: '10px',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Despite setting the text-xxs class with a font size of 10px in my configuration, the computed font size in the browser remains at 12px. I've also tried using the important variant for the font size utility, but it didn't seem to work either.

Any insights into  Tailwind CSS is not allowing me to set a font size smaller than 12px and how I can resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. As I understand, Tailwind CSS restricts font sizes to a minimum of 12px for accessibility and readability purposes but it is my client's requirement and I also want to learn how to resolve it. Thank you!

[image: Mobile ScreenShot]
[image]

https://shirshak-makestaff.vercel.app/login-hr-onboarding

Answer (score 0):

I found out with my approach it works when we open on mobile but when I inspect mobile device emulation in edge it will not go down from 12px.For now it is fine for me to continue project.
[image]

[image]

[image]